# Transfering data from HTML to external Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dropdown in HTML code which I am populating using angular. I want the selected value of that dropdown and send it to angular so that angular fetch the data from  database and populate in same HTML page. Below is my code.

index.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="sourceController" >
    <select class = "mdb-select md-form "  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="sourcesByName">
        <option class ="dropdown-item"  ng-repeat="source in showsource">{{source}}  </option>
    </select>

</div>
```

index.js

```
var Report = angular.module('Report', []);
Report.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.showdata = {}

// I want data here

// Get home page
 $http.get('/api/v1/table')
    .success(function(data) {
         $scope.showdata = data;
         console.log(data);
     })
     .error(function(error) {
         console.log('Error: ' + error);
     });
});


// Get all sources
Report.controller('sourceController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.showsource =[];
$http.get('/api/v1/sources')
   .success(function(data) {
      var l = data.length;
      data1=['Sources'];
      var i;
      for(i=0;i<l;i++){
         data1.push(data[i]["source"]);
      }
      $scope.showsource = data1;
    })
    .error(function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
  });
});
```

there is an table in my html page which I want to populate according to the dropdown value.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Perhaps create an angular scope-property "selectedValue", which is set in your `get.success(...)`-code and then reference the property with `{{ selectedValue }}`. Angular should pick up the change and re-render the new data. Or is that what you created `showdata` for?

Comment: Can  you explain it a bit more.I am new to this and didn't understand what you just said.

Comment: Can you show more code i.e your ddlSelect() method and the showsource array?

Comment: I have added showsource but ddlSelect() is a method which I am using for same purpose to get data from HTML to JS file.

Comment: should i add another controller for dropdown id in .get method?

Comment: Thanks for adding code. No you can do it in the mainController. I suggest you add an ng-model attribute to the select element. e.g ng-model="selectedValue" then you should also have an ng-change attribute which will get called when an option is selected. Then you can make the request for the new data according to what value was selected. I will write an answer for you shortly so you can see the code I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks Sarah code will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

| suggest you add an ng-model attribute to your select menu e.g

```
ng-model="selectedValue"
```

This will hold the value that is selected and you will be able to access this variable in your controller with `$scope.selectedValue`
You should also add an `ng-change` attribute to your select menu so that you can call a function whenever an option is selected.

## HTML select menu code:

```
 <select class="mdb-select md-form" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="selectSource()" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="sourcesByName">
    <option class="dropdown-item"  ng-repeat="source in showsource">{{source}}  </option>
 </select>
```

## In your mainController

```
var Report = angular.module('Report', []);
Report.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.showdata = {};

  $scope.selectSource = function(){
    //This function will be called whenever a new option is selected.
    //log the selectedValue to check it
    console.log($scope.selectedValue);
    //perform http request here with the selectedValue in order to retrieve
    //the corresponding data from the database.
    //Once the data is retrieved, we update the $scope.showdata variable. The view will be automatically updated.
  };

});
```

Comment: Hi Sarah, Thanks for your immediate response . However, I am getting undefined in $scope.selectedValue

Comment: Oh i see. Are the options with the "source" data displaying properly firstly? And can you try adding the selectSource function to your sourceController instead?

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It is working now.You are life saver.

Comment: Hi Sarah, this is out of question but can I call another controller similar to this in selectSource function. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Ayush. Just to clarify: You want to call a function from another controller in the selectSource function? Unfortunately this isn't possible. What is contained in the other function?

Comment: If you want to pass variables and methods between controllers you can define them in a factory and pass in the factory to the controllers. On a side note: Its a good idea to put your http requests in methods within a factory so that you keep the code in the controllers to a minimum.  :)

Comment: so is there a way to call more than one http request in one controller .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187266/discussion-between-sarah-and-ayush-goyal).